# Inertia global headers

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, axios, inertiajs

I'm trying to send a custom header (`Accept-Content-Language`) along with every request. This works for all regular axios requests, but inertia manual visits don't pick up on the header.

Here is the code in which I set the header:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const lang = localStorage.getItem('vue_i18n_locale');

if (lang) {
  axios.defaults.headers.common['Accept-Content-Language'] = lang;
  axios.defaults.headers.common['Accept-Language'] = lang;
}

window.axios = axios;
```

Simply trying to run:

```js
$inertia.post('some-route', { some: data })
```

I know about passing the header prop to the manual visit, but I want this header to be sent for every visit in the entire application without having to add them everywhere manually.

Is there any way to achieve this? My Google searches have told me no, but I hope someone on here will know better.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this one help you

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { InertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';

axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  const lang = localStorage.getItem('vue_i18n_locale');
  if (lang) {
    config.headers['Accept-Content-Language'] = lang;
    config.headers['Accept-Language'] = lang;
  }
  return config;
});

const app = document.getElementById('app');

new InertiaApp({
  resolve: (name) => import(`./Pages/${name}.vue`),
  setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
    return createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
      .use(plugin)
      .mount(el);
  },
  page: JSON.parse(app.dataset.page),
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not. I fear that inertia creates its own axios instance that I can't modify

Comment: Try using this with https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-axios to have Vue use a Axios global instance.